# Параметр класса в python

Tags: python, классы

Есть переменная `name`, и класс `test`, в `name` иногда меняется значение. Как создать параметр с именем, как значение в переменной `name`?

Если надо делать такое вне класса, то использовал `globals()[name]` и всё работало, но `self.globals()[name]` не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

```
name = 'p1'

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, name, 1)

test = Test()
print(test.p1)  # 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `__dict__`

```
name = 'p1'

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__[name] = 1

test = Test()
print(test.p1)    # Выведет: 1
```

UPD: Но вообще, лучше без особой нужды так не делать. В большинстве случаев можно просто создать в объекте один параметр-словарь, и в него складывать или забирать значения по имени.

Comment: Спасибо, щас попробую)

Comment: Я немного поправил ответ, чтобы был пример с self

Answer (score 0):

```
name = 'Василий'

class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def printName(self):
        return "Привет {}".format(self.name)

print(Test(name).printName())
Привет Василий

name = 'Александр'
print(Test(name).printName())
Привет Александр
```

Comment: Но это же совсем не то, о чём спрашивал автор вопроса. Параметр должен иметь ИМЯ, соответствующее строке в name, а не значение.

Comment: @Александр я понял так, а автор рассудит :)